# django: concatinating strings to create a url to static image in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to load an image whose url is composed of a vairable numerical value. 
Is there a template only solution to this or do I really have to create a filter in extras.py? I would rather just write this one liner. Something along the following lines:

```
{% with urltemp="media/"|add:info.personid|stringformat:"s"|add:".jpg"  %}
        <img src="{% static urltemp %}" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: for media url use this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix

Answer (score 1):

I know you can use `{% static your_url %}` but I allways prefer to do like this:

I have my images in `myproject/static/img/`

My `{{STATIC_URL}}` *(settings.py variable)* points to `myproject/static`

So in a template I usually do:    `<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/image_name.png" />`

Or using an `ImageField`

```
{% for item in item_list%}
    <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

In your case you could do:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ info.personid }}.jpg" />
```

`{{ MEDIA_URL }}` already ends with `/`

- You need `MEDIA_URL` to be defined in your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ info.personid }}.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        {% for name in image_list %}
          <div>
            <img src="{% static %}string_path/{{name.image}}.jpg" alt="img">
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
```